# Changing file Ownership with PowerShell 2.0

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, powershell, ntfs

We have an issue with a file server, whenever a user account is deleted the ownership of his/her files returns to their SID number, which shows up in our report as unknown.

Has anyone found a way to change the owner of a file to another user in PowerShell 2.0?

After escalating the issue to Google, it seems that this can’t be done.

I find it hard to believe that we are the only ones that have come across this issue?

We could change the owner via the Gui, but this would take a long time as we have a few thousand folders to change owners on.

Any help or findings would be great.

Thanks

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cosmoskey.blogspot.com/2010/07/setting-owner-on-acl-in-powershell.html

This should help you manage your goal sir.

It can be done, there are just some specific requirements for the user attempting the the ownership change, as well as the new owner.  The link I provided gives you all the details you should need.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.